# undefined method 'column_names' while creating model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently working in rails to build an administrative webapp. In my app context there are quests that players must complete to earn rewards. Each quest has a given amount of tasks to complete before allowing players to claim the reward.

Previously, the quest and tasks data were saved on a .txt file and have now been moved to a database structure. One of the functions my app must provide is read the .txt file and load the data to the database.

This is my task model and schema:

Model:

```
class QuestTask < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'quest_task'
    self.primary_key = :task_id

    has_many :player_task_progresses, :class_name => 'PlayerTaskProgress', :foreign_key => :task_id
    belongs_to :quest, :class_name => 'Quest', :foreign_key => :quest_id
    has_many :quest_task_texts, :class_name => 'QuestTaskText', :foreign_key => :task_id
end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "quest_task", primary_key: "task_id", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "quest_id",      limit: 4,                null: false
  t.integer "task_type",     limit: 4,                null: false
  t.integer "foreign_id",    limit: 4,  default: 0,   null: false
  t.string  "class",         limit: 64
  t.integer "amount",        limit: 4,  default: 0,   null: false
  t.string  "coordinates",   limit: 64
  t.float   "trigger_range", limit: 24, default: 0.0
end
```

Each time I attempt to run `QuestTask.create` it throws me the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `column_names' for nil:NilClass)
```

On the following piece of code in the controller:

```
data = {
    :quest_id => id,
    :exp_reward => d[key]['Exp'].to_i,
    :cash_reward => d[key]['Cash'].to_i,
    :pill_reward => d[key]['Gems'].to_i,
    :required_quest => d[key]['RequiredQuest'].to_i,
    :npc_id => d[key]['Survivor'].to_i,
    :player_needs_clan => d[key]['ClanRequired'].to_i,
    :required_level => d[key]['MinLevel'].to_i
}
begin
    quest = Quest.find(data[:quest_id])
    quest.update(data)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    quest = Quest.create(data)
end

#Task string example c:32:15|u:npc_sara
tasks = d[key]['Tasks'].split('|')
tasks.each do |task|
    tdata = {:task_id => nil,
        :quest_id => id
    }
    info = task.split(':')
    if info[0] == 'c'
        tdata[:task_type] = 1
        tdata[:foreign_id] = info[1].to_i
        tdata[:amount] = info[2].to_i
    elsif info[0] == 'k'
        tdata[:task_type] = 2
        tdata[:class] = info[1]
        tdata[:amount] = info[2].to_i
        if info[3] != '__NONE__'
            data[:map] = info[3]
        end
        tdata[:coordinates] = info[4]
        tdata[:trigger_range] = info[5]
    elsif info[0] == 'u'
        tdata[:task_type] = 4
        tdata[:class] = info[1]
        tdata[:amount] = 1
    elsif info[0] == 'w'
        tdata[:task_type] = 5
        tdata[:class] = info[1]
        tdata[:amount] = 1
    elsif info[0] = 'x'
        tdata[:task_type] = 6
        tdata[:class] = info[1]
    end
    print tdata
    res = QuestTask.find_by(quest_id: id.to_s)
    if res == nil
        print tdata
        QuestTask.create(tdata)
    else
        res.delete()
        QuestTask.create(tdata)
    end
```

In the previous code, the variable `d` is a hash that is built after parsing the data file and the variable `id` is user input.

The last tdata that I got, as an example, was:

```
{:task_id=>nil, :quest_id=>1, :task_type=>1, :foreign_id=>15, :amount=>5}
```

Changing task_id to a number makes no difference (It is set to auto_increment anyway).

Why is it throwing the error?

Comment: That part of the code has no problems and it does find the quest record in the database. If it doesn't exist, then I already caught the NotFound exception and it creates it instead of updating it. The problem is at the very end of the code I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create_table "quest_task", primary_key: "task_id", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "quest_id",      limit: 4,                null: false
  t.integer "task_type",     limit: 4,                null: false
  t.integer "foreign_id",    limit: 4,  default: 0,   null: false
->t.string  "class",         limit: 64
  t.integer "amount",        limit: 4,  default: 0,   null: false
  t.string  "coordinates",   limit: 64
  t.float   "trigger_range", limit: 24, default: 0.0
end
```

Change the column name, class is a reserved word.